# How to keep MySQL docker container running

Tags: docker

I have MySQL container running on a docker.

the container successfully launches and does not show any errors with following command:

```
docker container run --name mysqldb --network app -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=root -d mysql:8
```

but after several hours it exits on its own and shows:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS                    PORTS                                       NAMES
d02342ac6de7   mysql:8   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 days ago     Exited (137) 3 days ago                                               mysqldb
```

How to stop MySQL container exit and keep it running?

Comment: find out why it stops running (By checking the logs).

Comment: @Luuk, I have checked, it does not show it stops.

Answer (score 0):

Exit code `137` usually refers to OOM. Your Docker container runs out of memory after you run it for a few hours

You should stop your pending containers with `docker stop CONTAINER_ID` like:

```
docker stop d02342ac6de7
```

Or, if you don't need your other containers you can stop all of them with:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -aq)
```

Also, consider mounting a volume for your MySQL container so it uses your disk instead (refer to the [README](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) of MySQL images):

> Important note: There are several ways to store data used by
> applications that run in Docker containers. We encourage users of the
> mysql images to familiarize themselves with the options available,
> including:
>
> - Let Docker manage the storage of your database data by writing the
>   database files to disk on the host system using its own internal
>   volume management. This is the default and is easy and fairly
>   transparent to the user. The downside is that the files may be hard to
>   locate for tools and applications that run directly on the host
>   system, i.e. outside containers.
> - Create a data directory on the host
>   system (outside the container) and mount this to a directory visible
>   from inside the container. This places the database files in a known
>   location on the host system, and makes it easy for tools and
>   applications on the host system to access the files. The downside is
>   that the user needs to make sure that the directory exists, and that
>   e.g. directory permissions and other security mechanisms on the host
>   system are set up correctly.
>
> The Docker documentation is a good
> starting point for understanding the different storage options and
> variations, and there are multiple blogs and forum postings that
> discuss and give advice in this area.

So your run command would be like:

```
docker container run --name mysqldb -v /my/own/datadir:/var/lib/mysql --network app -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_DATABASE=root -d mysql:8
```